# I have a MacBook pro from 2020, and I want to lower the brightness lower than the default. How do I do it?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro from 2020 with a touch bar, and I want to lower the brightness lower than the default. How do I do it? My roommate keeps saying "Your MacBook screen keeps me awake". I'm running Monterey 12.2.1 if tat helps

Comment: In system settings or even on the touchbar. Or agree screen-off time as 11PM - 6AM or similar.

Comment: And closing it ? Except if you need to work on it.